# Tableau viz embedded is unable to sign In using SAML

Tags: .net, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I'm using JS-API to embed tableau viz portal widget on my website.

Tableau and my website use SAML and ADFS as SSO to authenticate users.

Usually a user goes to my website and logs in. After that, he can visit both the tableau site itself and the embedded widget. The embedded  widget does not have any dialogs. I guess it should take the cookies from ADFS itself, after user has identified during authentication on my website.

It always worked. The user simply logged into my website and already had access to the Tableau widget.

until we updated the tableau server.
Now if the user goes to my web site first, I started to see this failed request inside embedded widget:

```
NS_ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST
    
https://ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ec2.internal/vizportal/api/web/v1/auth/signin?path=/views/<aaaaaaa>/<bbbbbbb>?:embed=y...
Request Method: GET

scheme           https
host             ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX.ec2.internal
filename         /vizportal/api/web/v1/auth/signin
path             /views/<aaaaaaaa>/<bbbbbbbbb>?:embed=y...
siteUrlName      Transferred0 B (0 B size)
Referrer Policy  strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

If I open the tableau document directly in a new/separate tab and then go back to the my web site pagea with the embedded tableau widget and refresh page, everything starts working.

UPDATES:

On the page on my website, I see several requests happening inside an IFrame of the embedded tableau widget when an error occurs:

```
https://my-tableau/views/my-view/my-sheet?:embed=y...
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found

Response Headers: 
Server:                Tableau
Tableau_error_code:    0x285DFA77
Tableau_error_source:  Client
Tableau_service_name:  Unknown_Service
Tableau_status_code:   16
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Tableau:             Tableau Server


https://ip-112-11-46-111.ec2.internal/vizportal/api/web/v1/auth/signin?path=...
(failed) net::ERR_NAME_NOTE_RESOLVED
```

But when after this I opened Tableau in a separate tab (and tableau get authorized with ADFS sucessfully), and then refresh the page with the Talbeau widget, only one request was executed inside the IFrame, And everything starts to work:

```
https://my-tableau/views/my-view/my-sheet?:embed=y....
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

This is a part of the logs from Tableau server which appear when an error occurs (vizportal_node1-0.log):

```
2023-07-03 03:50:07.448 +0000 (,,,,) catalina-exec-4 : DEBUG com.tableausoftware.api.shared.StuckThreadInterceptor - thread 492 completed
2023-07-03 03:51:07.447 +0000 (,,,,) catalina-exec-1 : DEBUG com.tableausoftware.core.util.RemoteIP - Found header null in X-FORWARDED-PROTO
2023-07-03 03:51:07.447 +0000 (,,,,) catalina-exec-1 : DEBUG com.tableausoftware.core.util.RemoteIP - remoteAddr:127.0.0.1, remoteHost:127.0.0.1, x-forwarded-host:null, HTTP_HOST:localhost, SERVER_HOST:null, SERVER_ADDR:null, SERVER_PORT:null
2023-07-03 03:51:07.447 +0000 (,,,,) catalina-exec-1 : DEBUG com.tableausoftware.core.util.RemoteIP - trusted host set: [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, ip-112-11-46-111.ec2.internal/112.11.46.111]
2023-07-03 03:51:07.447 +0000 (,,,,) catalina-exec-1 : DEBUG com.tableausoftware.core.util.RemoteIP - trusted hostname set: [localhost, 112.11.46.111, ip-112-11-46-111.ec2.internal, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1]
2023-07-03 03:51:07.447 +0000 (,,,,) catalina-exec-1 : DEBUG com.tableausoftware.core.util.RemoteIP - Returning value based on gateway.public.host/port: ip-112-11-46-111.ec2.internal:80
2023-07-03 03:51:07.447 +0000 (,,,,) catalina-exec-1 : DEBUG com.tableausoftware.web.utils.WebSecurityUtils - Adding protocol and host "http://ip-112-11-46-111.ec2.internal:80" to relative redirect location "/"
2023-07-03 03:51:07.447 +0000 (,,,,) catalina-exec-1 : DEBUG com.tableausoftware.web.utils.WebSecurityUtils - http://ip-112-11-46-111.ec2.internal:80/
2023-07-03 03:51:07.453 +0000 (,,,,) catalina-exec-1 : DEBUG com.tableausoftware.api.shared.StuckThreadInterceptor - thread 489 with request uri /vizportal/api/status/check/health started
```

UPDATES:
SAML authorization in Embedded JS API Widget doesn't seem to work at all in FireFox

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the user api (not the official API) to log in to Tableau (vizportal), the fact you're not able to access is may be related with this:

[Tableau Server Leak Update](https://www.gosecure.net/blog/2022/07/13/tableau-server-leaks-sensitive-information-from-reflected-xss/)

This happened to me, I wrote a python script to log in and extract data, and even getting a response 200 on the authentication step, I coudn´t go through to the sign in.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm only using the JS API. Authorization is handled by the site in which the widget is embedded. This site receives a token from ADFS. And cookies are created on ADFS side. I expect that the tableau widget will go to ADFS and take the token, but it's not happends....